# There is three object in hashmap, how to access these object in a single statement?

Tags: java, collections

There is three object in Hash Map, how can we access these object in a single statement?

For example:

```
Map map=new HashMap();
map.put(1,"one");
map.put(2,"two");
map.put(3,"three");`
```

Comment: You should define whats access means to u in this context

Comment: you can write a method which will do this as one statement.

Answer (score 1):

Call map.values() and  you'll get a Collection of your 3 objects

Comment: Thanks Evgeniy Dorofeev for giving answer